# Draw Triangle in Java using MouseClicked

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java program to draw a triangle with vertices that are specified by the user's mouse clicks. So far I have gotten each coordinate pair into an array, called `points`, but I'm having trouble drawing the triangle.

Seeing as the coordinate pairs are of type `float` and the `drawLine()` method requires `int`, is there any way I could draw the lines by using `float`, or do I have to convert them to `int`?

Code

```
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int left = DrawingPanel.iX(-rWidth/2), right = DrawingPanel.iX(rWidth/2);
            int top = DrawingPanel.iY(rHeight/2), bot = DrawingPanel.iY(-rHeight/2);

            if(!(e.getX() > right || e.getX() < left ||
                    e.getY() < top || e.getY() > bot)) {
                clickCount++;
                if(clickCount >= 4) {
                    DrawingPanel.points[3] = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    DrawingPanel.ready = true;
                    drawingPanel.repaint();
                }
                else {
                    DrawingPanel.points[clickCount - 1] = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Must click inside red rectangle. Try again.");
        }
    });
```

`DrawingPanel` is a class I've created to draw the triangle.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/BuildPolygon.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assume you have a class called `DrawingPanel` which extends `Component` in some way and an instance of that class called `drawingPanel` of which you call the `repaint()` method.
First of all I wouldn't recommend accessing all the suff for drawingPanel in a static way, but that just as a side note.

If you want to draw you triangle you would have to override the `paint(Graphics g)` method in your `DrawingPanel` class.
Pasting that into you `DrawingPanel` class should do the trick:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    // This line is optional. It makes the edges of the triangle much smoother.
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    // Give the triangle whatever color you want.
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    int[] x = new int[3];
    int[] y = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Point p = points[i];
        x[i] = (int)p.getX();
        y[i] = (int)p.getY();
    }
    // Alternatively use g2.drawPolygon to just draw the outlines
    g2.fillPolygon(x, y, 3);

    g2.dispose();
}
```

(I haven't tested the code. I hope it works.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Point.x Point.y to draw your triangle. You don't need to play with int and float.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I created a class called `Point` where the two inputs are `float x` and `float y`